# Error accessing the SD card on Samsung Galaxy Note 3 KitKat (4.4.x)

Tags: android, sd-card, android-sdcard, ioexception, galaxy

Since Samsung updated the Note 3 to 4.4.x, I am getting the following exception when writing to the SD card:

```
java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:946)
at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1011)
```

My app has the necessary permission to write:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
     :  
    <application ... >
          :
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The code that creates the crash looks like this:

```
tempFile = File.createTempFile("anMoney", null, destinationFile.getParentFile());
```

`destionatioFile` points a file on the SD Card, so its parent file is the folder.

The error seems to be happening on Note 3 devices ONLY and other Samsung or non-Samsung devices are working fine. So this smells like a Note 3 bug, but is there some workaround I could perhaps do?

Comment: Please show the source code that is generating this error.

Comment: I updated the post with the call the crashes.

Comment: Note that `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` has nothing much to do with any "SD card". External storage has not been implemented as a removable bit of storage on most devices made since 2011. So, when you say that "destionatioFile points a file on the SD Card, so its parent file is the folder", do you literally mean some removable storage, or do you mean something on official external storage?

Comment: This is the real SD card.  The users have the option to type in a path, and the error is happening for those who type in the path to the real SD.

Comment: This is Samsung's response:
:This error might happen if your sd card is still locked as a usb device. make sure you're not using your phone as a usb storage. disconnect your device from the PC and try again. also you may have to add the following permission :
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />

Comment: I never heard of this permission.

Answer (score 3):

It's an error that seems to be confined to just a few Samsung models.  i.e. Note 3 (N9005).

The media_rw permission is missing in /system/etc/security/permissions.xml

```
<permission name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
<group gid="sdcard_r" />
<group gid="sdcard_rw" />
<group gid="media_rw" />
</permission>
```

You'll need to be rooted to fix it

Comment: Thanks.  Where did you find this info, if may I ask?

Comment: The "locked" external SD card only happened after applying KitKat to my Note 3.  I guessed it was a permissions thing, either at a file level or android permissions.

A few web searches with Google soon found a pattern and I went ahead and tried the solution you see above (after Rooting etc).

After a reboot, all was back to normal again.

BTW, xda-developers forum is a great resource for android dev stuff.

Comment: I don't think this is the case. Samsung is just the only one with SD cards and KitKat updates right now.

Comment: Just quick information, on my device with custom ROM, this directory is \system\etc\permissions\

Comment: Is there any API or command to check if this permission belongs to the "media_rw" group or not? Or more precisely, any way to check if the app can write to (anywhere on ) the sd-card? Also, what's the "sdcard_rw" for? does it do the same?

Answer (score 1):

This might be intended behavior based on a strict interpretation of Android's [external storage specs](http://source.android.com/devices/tech/storage/index.html#multi-user-external-storage):

> The WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission must only grant write access to
>   the primary external storage on a device. Apps must not be allowed to
>   write to secondary external storage devices, except in their
>   package-specific directories as allowed by synthesized permissions.

If you allow users to enter a path themselves it is likely that they will select something outside of your app's package-specific directory. In this case file write/creation/deletion will fail.

Comment: I certainly hope this isn't the case.

Comment: @Justin it's official now : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-platform/14VUiIgwUjY/UsxMYwu02z0J

Answer (score 1):

There are many articles talking about this issue, as Google and Samsung now don't allow third party apps to write to the sd-card, unless they write to their designated path .

Here are some links about it:

- http://lifehacker.com/android-kitkat-blocks-some-access-to-micro-sd-cards-1524997895
- http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/02/17/external-blues-google-has-brought-big-changes-to-sd-cards-in-kitkat-and-even-samsung-may-be-implementing-them/
- http://www.androidcentral.com/kitkat-sdcard-changes

Comment: When I posted this question two months ago, there weren't many articles talking about this.  But thanks.

Comment: Honestly, because you made it sound like I didn't do my homework before asking.

Comment: What should I do to fix it? I didn't mean to make it sound like that. I only wanted to refer to them...

Answer (score 0):

Access to removable storage was never officially supported by the Android SDK prior to Android 4.4, though many developers elected to ignore that.

Android 4.4 added some limited support for apps to have access to removable storage, via methods like `getExternalFilesDirs()` (note the plural). At the same time, [there are reports that some of the alternative ways that developers would work with removable storage are now locked down](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-platform/14VUiIgwUjY). Since I do not work with removable storage, I have not attempted to reproduce these results.

Comment: Well, not sure what's the point of having am SD card if apps can't write to it.....  Also, this only seems to effect the Note 3.  The Galaxy S4 is working fine.

Comment: @TomanMoney: "not sure what's the point of having am SD card if apps can't write to it" -- device manufacturers have rights to work with removable storage. And, so long as the manufacturers arrange for media on removable storage to be indexed by the media scanner for `MediaStore`, many apps do not need direct access to removable storage.